# How do I BIND in SMPP over a TLS connection using Kannel?

Tags: kannel

How do I BIND in SMPP over a TLS connection using Kannel?

I've looked at the documentation, and it only mentions HTTP, rather than SMPP.

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

use-ssl bool
 Defines whether we should try to bind with SSL enabled connection to create a SSMPP (secure SMPP) session.

http://www.kannel.org/download/kannel-userguide-snapshot/userguide.html